# DateTime incorrect month and how convert to dd/mm/yyyy in database

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to let the user choose a Date from a `DatePicker` and store it into database, and then convert it to dd/mm/yyyy format.

```
        dp =(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.DateActivity);
        setDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            requestDate.setText("Day" + dp.getDayOfMonth() + " Month " + (dp.getMonth() + 1)+ " Year " + dp.getYear());
        }
    });
```

The output is `Day 9 Month 2 Year 2014`.
The output months is less by one for every month I choose so I add 1 to the month. Why this is the case?
But the main problem is how do I convert it to `09022014` and store it in the database? If the db has the format dd/mm/yyyy does it means it will not accept my output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Calendar` treats the months as a zero-based list, so the DatePicker follows this convention as well (see the documentation for [DatePicker.init](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29)).  It's confusing, but that's just the way Java does it (for now, at least).  Adding 1 like you're doing will work just fine.

As for converting the date, you can use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to format the date however you like.  For what you said, the format pattern string would be `"ddMMyyyy"`.  See the sample code below:

```
// Build Calendar object from DatePicker fields.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, myDatePicker.getMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, myDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, myDatePicker.getYear());

// Convert date to desired format.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
String dateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(dateString); // if you want it as an int instead
```

You may want to consider storing the date as 20140209 (`"yyyyMMdd"`, year-month-day) instead for sorting purposes, as that will naturally allow it to be sorted chronologically.

Comment: I done it and it did display the 0. but i change it to ddMMyyyy because that is the format decided by my team so i just follow it. but as it is a while string, whill the db recognise the date from the month/year? like in case we would want to retrieve it seperately.

Comment: @Myst Ah, yes, your change is correct based on what you said in the question - I must've read it incorrectly.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Myst As for your question... like you said, the value will be a string - SQLite does not have a "date" type (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  If you want to be able to query separately by year, month, and/or day, you will need to have some additional logic to separate them.  You could either make separate year, month, and day columns and query on those, or write wrapper logic in Java to filter the results after the query is done.  If I misinterpreted your question, let me know.

Comment: wait..i just been notified that the string will have to be 01/02/2014..how do i insert the "/" in the format?

Comment: i just change the format to dd/MM/yyyy and it works. i did not expect it to work. output. 08/12/2014.

Comment: Yes, you got it:  you can enter any other formatting characters (like "/" or "-") straight into the format string, as long as it's not one of the interpreted symbols on the SimpleDateFormat list.

Answer (score 2):

For your second problem (putting it into the database) you can simply create a string like this:

```
String todb = dp.getDayOfMonth() + "/" + (dp.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + dp.getYear();
```

Which will return a string like `09/21/2014`.

Now, as for your first problem (the month being off by one), I believe this stems from a [`CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener.html). It says:

> month The month that was set [0-11].

I would bet that this was also implemented on `DatePicker`'s (or you're using the `CalendarView` with the `DatePicker`), so January is 0 and December is 11. So your way of changing the month by 1 is a perfectly fine way to do it.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I'm not sure why the DatePicker is like that but i'm glad i solved it. i tried the String todb but it displayed 9/2/2014. which i think without the 0 may be the correct way as 0 may not be part of the date usually displayed if it is single digit. but i not sure how will the database will see it as. or it will automatically make a 09 when stored. or turn out 00922014. i havent implement the database so i'm not  sure.

Comment: @Myst It honestly depends what database you're using. If it's SQLite (or any other database), you can probably make it work with the way I'm doing it above, so just try it and see.

Comment: yes i'm using SQLite. ok i test it while and see. database still need some day to finish problems on that end, so i've to wait a few days and see. thanks

Comment: @Myst Have you tested it?

Comment: no. due to some problems i can only tested it maybe tommorrow, i just converted it to a string first. with 0102014.